# Why a default javascript value for a BIRT report parameter is not evaluated in the deployed webapp?

Tags: birt

I want to add a default value as javascript for a report parameter so I did the following (in the eclipse birt designer):

[image: reportDesignerAddParameter]

The problem I have is: when I deploy the app (that contains the report) the javascript is not evaluated:[image: webpageReportParamsJavascriptInDefaultValueNotEvaluated]

However, when I preview the report in the birt report designer it evaluates the javascript default value:

[image: birtViewerJavascriptIsEvaluated]

Here is the code that I use (filtered to have only the relevant stuff):

```
  IReportRunnable design = getReportRunnable(pathToTemplate);
  IRunAndRenderTask task = _birtReportEngine.createRunAndRenderTask(design);

  task.setRenderOption(options);
  task.getAppContext().put(EngineConstants.APPCONTEXT_CLASSLOADER_KEY, ReportEngine.class.getClassLoader());

  task.setParameterValues(parameters);
  task.validateParameters();

  task.run();
```

The question is: did I miss something? Should I add an option somewhere that forces the evaluation of the default javascript expression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you show is the code for creating and rendering a report but it's not the code for displaying the parameter form.

Are you using the Birt-Webviewer or a self developed Web App?

In the latter case and if you retrieve the default parameter values per `org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.IScalarParameterDefn.getDefaultValue()`, the javascript expression will not be evaluated.

To get default paramater values with expressions evaluated you have to use the engine task IGetParameterDefinitionTask and there the method `org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.IGetParameterDefinitionTask.getDefaultValue(IParameterDefnBase arg0)`.